# Selenium (Java) - Unable to manipulate a popup

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a web application I have been working with and creating automations. I have hit a block on on a specific step where I click a button, which then opens a popup. On this popup there is only a dropdown and a button to submit.

button and popup:

[image: button and popup]

It looks to me like the popup is just in a div and or section. I took a clip of the code for the element

```
    <div class="modalHost ui-front" style="opacity: 1;"><div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-dialog-buttons tixui5-modal-dialog ui-draggable ui-resizable" data-bind="css: customCssClass" id="tixui5-modal-dialog-01710183997144" data-view="Modules/Platform/ModalDialog" data-active-view="true" style="opacity: 1; position: absolute; width: 400px; top: 352.632px; left: 751px; min-height: 100px; max-height: 455.375px; max-width: 1804px;">
    <script id="tixui5-modal-dialog-01710183997144-translations" type="application/json">
{
  "Ok": "Ok",
  "Cancel": "Cancel"
}
</script>

    <!-- DIALOG HEADER -->
    <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix ui-draggable-handle">
        <!--ko if: modalDialogHeaderIcon --><!-- /ko -->
        <span class="ui-dialog-title" id="tixui5-modal-dialog-01710183997144-header" data-bind="text: dialogCaption">Create Raw Material Mill</span>
        <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="Close" data-bind="command: cancelCommand, button: { icon: 'fa fa-times' , showLabel: false }"><span class="ui-button-icon ui-icon fa fa-times"></span><span class="ui-button-icon-space"> </span></button>
    </div>
    <!-- DIALOG CONTENT -->
        <div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" id="tixui5-modal-dialog-01710183997144-content" data-bind="compose: contentViewModel" style="max-height: 379.409px;"><div class="durandal-wrapper" data-view="Views/Dialogs/CopyRawMaterialMillDialog" data-active-view="true" style="opacity: 1; position: static;"><script id="bom-common-dialogs-copyrawmaterialmilldialog-msg" type="application/json">
{
  "BomAddRawMaterialMill": "Create Raw Material Mill",
  "BomCopyRawMaterialMill": "Copy Raw Material Mill"
}
</script><section id="bom-common-dialogs-copyrawmaterialmilldialog">
    <article id="bom-common-dialogs-copyrawmaterialmilldialog-content">
        <div class="tipsui5-container24">
            <div class="rowheight-oneline-flex">
                <div class="grid12 tixui5-lint-div-label">
                <label data-bind="tipsui5FlexibleFor: 'bom-common-dialogs-copyrawmaterialmilldialogmillcode-combo'" class="tipsui5-label" for="bom-common-dialogs-copyrawmaterialmilldialogmillcode-combo_iqUFH0">Mill Code
                </label></div>
                <div class="grid12 grid-flex">
                <select id="bom-common-dialogs-copyrawmaterialmilldialogmillcode-combo_iqUFH0" class="tixui5-select tixui5-input-required" data-bind="options: millCodeOptions, value: selectedMillCode, valueAllowUnset: true, required: true, optionsText: &quot;displayText&quot;, optionsValue: &quot;code&quot;, tipsui5FlexibleId: &quot;bom-common-dialogs-copyrawmaterialmilldialogmillcode-combo&quot;, tixui5ComboboxEmptyElement: { options: millCodeOptions, noemptyline: true }" autofocus="">
                <option value="ALL">ALL - Production location</option><option value="EAD">EAD - EAD</option><option value="EAG">EAG - EAG</option>
                </select></div>
            </div>
            <!-- ko if: isCopyMode --><!-- /ko --> <!-- End of isCopyMode -->
            <!-- ko if: $root.costValueVisible --><!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </article>
</section></div></div>

        <!-- DIALOG BUTTONS -->
        <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix tixui5-dialog-button-container">
            <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset" data-bind="foreach: allButtons">
                <button data-bind="button: {label: caption },command: buttonCommand, attr:{'id': 'tixui5-modal-dialog-0' + '-button-' + id}, css: buttonRole" class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget tixui5-button tixui5-button-primary" id="tixui5-modal-dialog-01710183997144-button-OK">OK</button>
            
                <button data-bind="button: {label: caption },command: buttonCommand, attr:{'id': 'tixui5-modal-dialog-0' + '-button-' + id}, css: buttonRole" class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget tixui5-button tixui5-button-secondary" id="tixui5-modal-dialog-01710183997144-button-Cancel">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div style="display: block; z-index: 90;" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div><div style="display: block; z-index: 90;" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div><div style="display: block; z-index: 90;" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se"></div></div></div>
```

I have tried accessing and or manipulating this button and drop down via xpath and ID, but in both cases, I cannot seem to do anything with it.

```
WebElement createRawMatMill = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html//select[contains(@id,'bom-common-dialogs-copyrawmaterialmilldialogmillcode-combo')]"));
    Select rawMaterialMillDD = new Select(createRawMatMill);
    createRawMatMill.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
    createRawMatMill.click();
    rawMaterialMillDD.selectByIndex(12);
```

I added in a script to see if it had handles, but nothing is printing out so I assume its not actually a new window.

```
String mainWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
            Set<String> allWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
            Iterator<String> iterator = allWindowHandles.iterator();

            // Here we will check if child window has other child windows and will fetch the heading of the child window
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String ChildWindow = iterator.next();
                    if (!mainWindowHandle.equalsIgnoreCase(ChildWindow)) {
                    driver.switchTo().window(ChildWindow);
                    WebElement text = driver.findElement(By.id("sampleHeading"));
                    System.out.println("Heading of child window is " + text.getText());
```

Im a little stumped as to how to proceed. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Note: In reviewing this further, could this be a modal container? I am messing around with that a bit now.

Comment: Its not a new window but the element could be part of an iframe

Comment: Please post HTML as a text, and not a screenshot.

Comment: There is an iframe in the footer of the page, but I don't believe its related here. I did try to change to the frame, but it did not make a difference.

Comment: HTML added as text